# How should I render multi-state component, which fetches API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am using React with Node.js.

I have a component `ItemList`, which fetches some API in the `componentDidMount()` method, because it allows me to easily render a "loading state".

I need to pass a state to this component, which would change the API's url using a toggle button. This toggle button is an individual component (`ToggleButton`). These two components are siblings and I am using parent as a way for these components to communicate.

I thought Context is perfect for this kind of job. The issue is, that using React's Context is just re-rendering (calling the function `render()` of a `ItemList` and not remounting the component, thus not calling the `componentDidMount()` method or even constructing the component again).

```
export const ToggleContext = React.createContext({
    switched: false
});
```

```
export default class Items extends React.Component
{
    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props)
        
        this.state = {
            switched: false
        }

        this.toggleSwitch = () => {
            this.setState(state => ({
                switched: !state.switched
            }))
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        console.log(this.state.switched)
        return (
            <>
                <div class="page-header">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <h2 class="h5 mb-0">Items</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <section class="py-0">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                        <ToggleContext.Provider value={this.state.switched}>
                            <ToggleButton callFunc={this.toggleSwitch}/>
                            <ItemList loadWeb={this.state.switched}/>
                        </ToggleContext.Provider>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

`ItemList` component is heavily inspirated by [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

I am succesfully getting the changed state through `ToggleButton` in parent component, sending it to `ItemList` and picking it up as `props.loadWeb`, I am just not sure if my implementation is wrong or even if what I demand is possible with Context.

Is it possible to reconstruct the whole component using context, should I use refs, sould I fetch the API in the `render()` method, etc.?

Comment: So is everything currently working as expected with the only question being "am I doing it correctly"?

Comment: @codemonkey not really, the code with my current approach doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that you need your `componentDidMount` called on every toggle of `ItemList`. But as you noted, it does not remount every time. As such, using `componentDidUpdate` inside your `ItemList` is more appropriate to toggle that API link.

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

I also encourage you to check out this article on using Hooks vs Classes: https://blog.bitsrc.io/6-reasons-to-use-react-hooks-instead-of-classes-7e3ee745fe04

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing seems right, I would say, you could probably simplify (in my opinion) by using **function components** along with **hooks**.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Items = () => {
  const [toggled, toggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="page-header">
        <h2 class="h5 mb-0">Items</h2>
      </div>

      <section class="py-0">
        <ToggleButton callFunc={toggle(!toggled)}/>
        <ItemList loadWeb={toggled}/>
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: This won't solve his problem. He needs `ItemList` to remount on every toggle.

Comment: Doing this proceeded my render() method to go into infinite loop for some reason.

Comment: So he does, teach me to read the question twice, before jumping in.